# Client/Server program that rejects a client connection by his name

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am writing a small client/server program and I need to make the user join the server by his name and make the server accept or reject according to that name whether it is used (will be rejected) or accepted otherwise.

```
public class server {
    ServerSocket ss;
    ArrayList<Client> clients; // this should be the connected clients 

    public server(int port) throws IOException{
        this.ss = new ServerSocket(port);  
    }

    public void respond(){}
}

public class Client {
    Socket s;
    String name;  

    public Client(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void join(String name){
        // this method should ask to connect to a server by name.
    }
}
```

My question specifically is how can a client join a server by his name? Can I add the server as an attribute in the client class to call the respond method in server class or what?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking... You just open the socket and are able to send data through it on the client using the input and output streams.

Comment: @Reinard , I already know this but what happens is that the serversocket accepts the connection and make a new socket without knowing the client name ,I want the server not to accept new clients with used name .

Comment: @user3423255 why not create a list / map of used client names and when a user tries to connect, authenticate that name against your list / map?

Comment: @EvanBechtol ,I am trying to do this but when the serversocket accepts a client it doesn't know his name ,It just accepts and make a new scoket,so how can I add the name to the list when a client is connected successfully .

Comment: Periodically send the client a heartbeat message from the server. This will tell you if the client is connected to the server. If the heartbeat returns positively, then their username stays in the list.

Comment: @EvanBechtol , How can the server send messages to it's clients ?

Comment: @user3423255 Try this: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html